# XHTML java snippet with Google Pretty print

Tags: java, xhtml, format

I am looking at options to insert a Java SE code snippet into my XHTML document. I found Google's 'google-code-prettify' but cannot find any templates that seem to fit best for displaying code snippets with line numbers etc. Has anyone had any experience with using google-code-prettify with java source, or is there another plugin I can try?

Edit: I updated my xhtml so it currently looks like this. I then updated the prettify.css source to include the code provided in below comments.

```
<link href="prettyprint\google-code-prettify\src\prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettyprint\google-code-prettify\src\prettify.js"></script>
```

My java source is still centered, and not indented to the left. Do I need to update the .js file or .css further to accomplish this?

Answer: I wrapped my pre tag inside a div called codesnippet. Below is the code in the css that fixed this for me.

```
#codesnippet li{text-align:left; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the following code in your `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

Then put your code in `<pre>` tags like this.

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java linenums">
```

```java
public class Foo {

    public void bar(){
        System.out.println("Foo.bar");
    }

}
```

```html
</pre>
```

***EDIT:***

Here's my CSS.

```css
.pln { color: #000000 }
.str { color: #DD1144 }
.kwd { color: #000000; font-weight: bold }
.com { color: #999988; font-style: italic }
.typ { color: #445588; font-weight: bold }
.lit { color: #008080 }
.pun, .opn, .clo { color: #000000 }
.tag { color: #080080 }
.atn { color: #7F0055 }
.atv { color: #008008 }
.dec, .var { color: #2A00FF }
.fun { color: #FF0000 }
li.L0, li.L1, li.L2, li.L3, li.L4, li.L5, li.L6, li.L7, li.L8, li.L9 { color: #999988; }
 li.L0, li.L2, li.L4, li.L6, li.L8 { background: #F5F5F5; }
```

It renders on my page like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code is highlighted correctly, but its centered and only has 1 line number (5). Do I need to use a custom css sheet to further modify or something?

Comment: @Shijima I've posted my CSS. Make sure you change the colors to match your page style.

Comment: It's getting closer to what I need. Instead of pointing to https for the run_prettify.js script, I downloaded the source and edited the pretiffy.css file. The numbers are now coming but the code is still centered and not indented properly. Please see above edit to how I am declaring in my xhtml. Is there some additional change needed to the original prettify.css file, or did you also need to change something in the .js file as well?

Comment: Got it to work! After playing around with it for a bit I was able to add 1 line of code to your provided css, I added the snippet in my original post.